# Selection of inherited operator contrary to `using` clause in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance

In the following example struct `S` inherits from two functional objects `A` and `B` each with its own `operator ()`, and then declares `using A::operator()` to take the operator from `A`:

```
using A = decltype([](int){ return 1; });
using B = decltype([](){ return 2; });

struct S : A, B {
    using A::operator();
};

int main() {
    S s;
    static_assert( s() == 2 ); // passes in GCC and Clang, but why?
}
```

As I expected, this code is rejected by MSVC with the error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

because `A::operator(int)` indeed takes 1 argument and `B::operator()` shall not be considered.

However both GCC and Clang accept the code and call `B::operator()` in `static_assert`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x6x3aWzoq

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: I have another question: why is `static_assert` allowed? Is `s()` `constexpr`? Why?

Comment: @Eugene. Lambda's `operator()` is implicitly `constexpr` since C++17.

Comment: Clang [even compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Pj8ah6jb4) without `using A::operator()`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 looks like https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC (and Clang) are correct in this case.

A captureless nongeneric lambda has a conversion function to function pointer ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure#8.sentence-1)), which is inherited by `S` (and doesn't conflict since the conversion functions from `A` and `B` convert to different types). So during overload resolution for a function call expression like `s()`, surrogate call functions are introduced for each conversion function ([[over.call.object]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.call.object#2)). The one introduced from `B`'s conversion function is the only viable candidate, so it is selected by overload resolution, and the call is performed by converting `s` to a function pointer first and calling that.

You can see this by actually compiling a `s();` call with optimization disabled; a call to the conversion function will be emitted.

---

IIRC MSVC's lambdas have *multiple* conversion functions to function pointers for all the different calling conventions, which makes the overload resolution ambiguous.

Comment: Yep, checks out. Cannot delete my answer so will amend mine and let the OP know.  Have a +1 anyway. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This is an equivalent code to the question, but without lambdas: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/38T35Yfvs